# Using $this within a singleton

Tags: php, singleton, hook, wordpress

I'm trying to create a singleton to process some form data, however I can't figure out how to effectively set/reference the variables within the class.

The idea is that, on submission, a function `getpostdata()` is called that creates a new instance in the class `meta` and saves the array `$_POST['ids']` to `$this->ids` within the class.  A filter is then used to send another piece of data to a function within the same class; however when I try to make reference to `$this->ids` within that function I get the following error:

> Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in public_html/wp-content/plugins/myplugin/myplugin.php

Below is the code:

```
class meta 
{
    # Singleton
    protected static $instance = NULL;

    public $ids;  

    private function __construct() {}

    public static function get_instance() 
    {
        NULL === self::$instance and self::$instance = new self;
        return self::$instance;
    }
    public function post_info($info)
    {
        $this->ids = $info;
        echo "good deal";
        return $this->ids;
    }

    public function metafunction($usermeta)
    {
        echo "<br/>Dumping USERMETA: ";
        var_dump($usermeta);
        var_dump( $this->ids );
        die();
    }
}
add_filter('filter', 'meta::metafunction');

add_action('action', 'getpostdata');

function getpostdata(){
    var_dump($_POST['ids']);
    $a=meta::get_instance();
    $info=$_POST['ids'];
    $a->post_info($info);
    echo "<br/>A vardump: ";
    var_dump($a);
}
```

The output comes as follows:

```
array(3) { [0]=> string(4) "test" [1]=> string(5) "test1" [2]=> string(5) "test2" } infodump: testgood deal
A vardump: object(meta)#110 (1) { ["ids"]=> array(3) { [0]=> string(4) "test" [1]=> string(5) "test1" [2]=> string(5) "test2" } } 
Dumping USERMETA: array(4) { ["field_1"]=> string(4) "test" ["field_2"]=> string(4) "test" ["profile_field_ids"]=> string(3) "1,2" ["password"]=> string(34) "$P$BEgv26F57KKv/.dGpNcWip1Tbb8zyK0" } Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in public_html/wp-content/plugins/myplugin/myplugin.php
```

My guess is that my call from the filter isn't kosher but if anyone has any suggestions I'd be delighted.

Comment: I think the problem isn't the singleton, it's that you're making a static call to meta::metafunction. My 15 second analysis, I think you need to instantiate meta with something like `$test = meta::get_instance();` and then call `add_filter('filter', '$test->metafunction');`

Comment: @mkaatman FTW!  Thanks so much; do write your response up as an answer so I can properly credit you (if you like).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem isn't the singleton, it's that you're making a static call to `meta::metafunction`. My 15 second analysis, I think you need to instantiate meta with something like

`$test = meta::get_instance();` and then call `add_filter('filter', '$test->metafunction');`

Answer (score 0):

Do you mind me changing your code around a bit?

I think you need to call `new` on the class you create to instantiate an object. Once you have an object, then you can call `$this->` on it.

```
<?php
class meta 
{
    public $ids;  

    public function meta() {} //this replaces __construct()


    public function post_info($info)
    {
        $this->ids = $info;
        echo "good deal";
        return $this->ids;
    }

    public function metafunction($usermeta)
    {
        echo "<br/>Dumping USERMETA: ";
        var_dump($usermeta);
        var_dump($this->ids);
        die();
    }
}

function getpostdata(){
    //using $array here as a placeholder for $_POST data
    $array = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3); //$_POST['ids'];
    var_dump($array);

    //This line in specific
    $a = new meta();

    $info = $array; //$_POST['ids'];
    $a->post_info($info);
    echo "<br/>A vardump: ";
    var_dump($a);
}

getpostdata();

?>
```

Here is the php manual on Classes: http://php.net/manual/en/keyword.class.php

Comment: Thanks for the response!  How should I use the filter to send `$usermeta` to `metafunction()`?  Would it be ok to use it as I had been?  Also, I'm not sure but I believe the above isn't a singleton; is there any reason you decided against using the singleton pattern?  Many thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I would use:

```
$your_plugin = new meta();

add_filter('filter', array($your_plugin, 'metafunction'));
```

See [WP Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_filter)